# Flexbox expands outside container instead of wrapping

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have 3 flexboxes each inside the other. The outermost flexbox(`.flex-1`) holds the title and the next flexbox(`.flex-2`), which holds the button and the innermost flexbox(`.flex-3`), which holds a few `.item`s. Ideally, the items will flow down and then when there is no space left (based on the size of the outermost box) should wrap to the right. This works if a height is explicitly set on `.flex-3`, but I am not able to do that because the title varies in height.

Instead, it overflows and items are shown below the border of `.flex-1`, as well as `flex-2` expanding to fit them and overflowing.

```css
  .title{width: 100%}
  
  .flex-1{ /* Title and flex-2 */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 700px;
    height: 700px;
    border: 4px black solid;
  }
  
  .flex-2{ /* flex-3 and button */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    border: 3px #333 solid;
    align-items: flex-start;
  }
  
  .flex-3{ /* contains items */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    border: 2px #888 solid;
    flex-grow: 1;
  }
  
  .item{
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    border:1px #DDD solid;
  }
```

```html
<div class='flex-1'>
  <h3 class='title'>THIS IS A TITLE</h3>
  <div class='flex-2'>
    <div class='flex-3'>
      <div class='item'></div>
      <div class='item'></div>
      <div class='item'></div>
      <div class='item'></div>
      <div class='item'></div>
      <div class='item'></div>
    </div>
    <button>BTN</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be caused by the CSS property `align-items` on `.flex-2`.

Try removing this.

Comment: No, this does not fix the problem.

Comment: Presumably different per browser then. Firefox 47 on linux, does not work: http://i.imgur.com/CDUyHBp.png

Comment: Can the title tag be outside of `.flex-1`? If so, you can fix it by setting `height:100%` on the child div: https://jsfiddle.net/su2a5m11/1/

Comment: And indeed, `align-items` doesn't seem to work as expected in Firefox. It would be the correct answer though.